# ListView LostFocus Event isn't working fine

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I've a listview and a textBLOCK inside it. I want to collapse the visibility of listview when I tap anywhere else on my screen. I tried to do this using LostFocus Event for my listview but it is fired ONLY when I selected an item. Why does it behave like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextBlock's Leave or LostFocus event because if you focus the TextBlock, the ListView losts focus but if you focus TextBlock when you focused something out of ListView, the ListView never becomes focus.

Comment: Who wants to focus listview? What i want is just to create an event that is fired when i tap anywhere on the screen except on my Listview.

Comment: @Zoya I try and found something you can use listviews Leave event it gives what you want

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this as of right now, based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/26ade33e-25f7-4bb8-a987-10f8b40ce30c/hit-test-for-windows-store-apps?forum=winappswithcsharp) seems to be to hook into the touch input directly from the `CoreWindow` and then each time compare the point on the touch input with the bounds of the `ListView` relative to the `CoreWindow`.

The [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) may assist in this by adding such extensions as `GetBoundingRect` to `FrameworkElement`s.

Answer (score 0):

I used the IsTabStop Property. Actually i have a user control in in which i'm having this Listview. I did the following steps:

- I set the IsTabStop property of UserControl to "True".
- Then I set the focus to the textblock when it is tapped by doing:

  ```
  this.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
  ```
- Then created the LostFocus Event of my UserControl and Collapsed the visibility of ListView.